# Do firewalld rich-rules apply irrespective of the allowed services in a zone?

Tags: amazon-ec2, firewall, linux-networking, firewalld, security-groups

**Context:** I have `firewalld` running on an AWS EC2.

**Goal:** I want to add a rich rule to the default zone (public) that allows traffic from a certain CIDR range/IP address range/subnet over port 443 (HTTPS) via the TCP protocol. I'm adding this rule to the `public` zone via `firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="[CENSORED]" port port=443 protocol=tcp accept'`

**Question:** Once I add this rich rule will it still apply (allow traffic through) even if the services listed when I run `firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-all` only include `ssh   dhcpv6-client`?

Answer (score 0):

After testing on the target servers, yes, firewalld rich-rules apply irrespective of zone level service (and other configs for that matter).